# TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined. Any suggestion?

Tags: reactjs

[image: Click here for image]
I am getting this error. I know the array is empty/undefined but thats the problem. The is not being filled where it is marked in the picture.

Comment: When you've a chance you should update your question to include an actual code snippet instead of an image. Images aren't searchable and can be more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the braces around arrow function mappings to return and propagate the result, or simply add a return. e.g.

```js
.then(response => {response.json()})
```

should be

```js
.then(response => response.json())
```

or

```js
.then(response => { return response.json(); })
```

The top one returns nothing (`undefined`) and if you're filtering that later, you'll get that error message.

Comment: Thank you. Will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning a value in the Promise chain, you need to return the JSON Promise in the Promise chain so it's available to update in state.

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(...)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json(); // <-- return this Promise
    })
    .then(users => {
      this.setState({ robots: users });
    });
}
```

You can alternatively use the arrow function's implicit return.

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(...)
    .then(response => response.json()) // <-- return this Promise
    .then(users => {
      this.setState({ robots: users });
    });
}
```